# Donot keep logger.info() statement in nohup.out

Tags: python, flask, nohup

I have coded a flask application on server.
I run it like below :-

```
export FLASK_APP=mypyhthonfile
nohup flask run --host=host-ip --port=port-number
```

The python script has logger statements like:

```
Logger.info("this is a log")
```

The logger statements are printed in both the logger file and nohup.out

What is the way to avoid printing logger statements in nohup.out ?

Comment: You can disable logging to standard error but it's not clear from your problem statement if that's what you *actually* want.

Comment: I want that the logger.info() statements(in python script) should not be written to nohup.out

Comment: Configure it to log to a file. https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html

Comment: @tripleee I have already done that and the issue is that logs are stored to both `nohup.out` and `python log file`; when it should be stored in only python log file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your logger in lower level than root logger:

In this example I set root logger to logging.WARNING (30) level and my test_logger is set to logging.DEBUG (10) so the root logger ( which nohup is listening to ) will not print anything (only string that you printed or have higher logging levels than 30) and there are logs that has more levels than logger's level in example.log.

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log', level=logging.WARNING)
test_logger = logging.getLogger('test')
test_logger.setLevel(level=logging.DEBUG)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I will check and let you know